# Computing gradients for Module class in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I created a tiny test case that implements a PyTorch inspired module class in JAX. The forward method works as expected. However, when I try to compute the gradients for the weights in the linear layer, I end up with a single gradient that probably belongs to the loss. How do I compute the gradients for the weights in my classes in JAX?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp


class Module:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __call__(self, inputs: jax.Array):
        return self.forward(inputs)


class Linear(Module):
    def __init__(self, key: jax.Array, in_features: int, out_features: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features

        key_w, key_b = jax.random.split(key=key, num=2)
        self.weights = jax.random.normal(key=key_w, shape=(out_features, in_features))
        self.biases = jax.random.normal(key=key_b, shape=(out_features,))

    def forward(self, inputs: jax.Array) -> jax.Array:
        out = jnp.dot(self.weights, inputs) + self.biases
        return out
    

class Activation(Module):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        pass

    def forward(self, inputs: jax.Array) -> jax.Array:
        return jax.nn.sigmoid(inputs)
    

class Model(Module):

    def __init__(self, key: jax.Array, in_features: int, out_features: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = Linear(key=key, in_features=in_features, out_features=out_features)
        self.activation = Activation()

    def forward(self, inputs: jax.Array) -> jax.Array:
        out = self.linear(inputs)
        out = self.activation(out)
        return out
    

def criterion(output: jax.Array, target: jax.Array):
    return ((target - output) ** 2).sum()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    in_features: int = 4
    out_features: int = 1

    key = jax.random.PRNGKey(67)

    model = Model(key=key, in_features=in_features, out_features=out_features)

    key = jax.random.PRNGKey(68)
    data = jax.random.normal(key=key, shape=(in_features,))

    out = model(data)
    print(f"{out = }")
    loss = criterion(output=out, target=2) 
    print(f"{loss = }")

    target = jnp.array([2.0])
    grads = jax.grad(criterion)(out, target)
    print(f"{grads = }")
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute gradients in JAX, you need two things:

1. you need a function that takes as arguments the parameters you'd like to differentiate with respect to, and returns the target value (e.g. the loss).
2. you need those parameters to be in a form that is understandable to `grad` and other JAX transformations.

In your case, you might satisfy (1) by doing something like this:

```py
def loss(model, data):
  return criterion(model(data), target=2)

result = grad(loss, argnums=0)(model, data)
```

Satisfying (2) is a bit more involved for the code you've written: essentially you need to register your `Model` class as a PyTree (see https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytrees.html#extending-pytrees) so JAX knows which attributes of the model to differentiate with respect to. You can either do that manually via `register_pytree_node`, or you can use a JAX-based framework like [flax](https://flax.readthedocs.io/) or [equinox](https://github.com/patrick-kidger/equinox) that gives you a pre-registered class hierarchy to work with.